# Hibernate Many to one Mapping with different Number of columns

Tags: java, database, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping

Hi I have 2 tables as below

***Table1:***

```
    +-------------------+
    | ID  LOB col1 col2 |
    +-------------------+
```

Primary Key (ID and LOB)

***Table2:***

```
    +-----------------+
    | SK ID col3 col4 |
    +-----------------+
```

Primary Key (SK)

I ***need to give a many to one relation from table 2 to table1***, since **table1** has **compositePrimaryKey(ID and LOB)** but **table2** does not have **any column related to LOB**. I am unable to provide the Mapping.
Please help on this.

**EDIT** I have tried hibernate mapping for Table2:

```
<many-to-one name="class1Obj" class="com.acs.enterprise.common.Class1" 
            lazy="proxy" insert="false" update="false">
    <column name="ID" />
    <column name="LOB" />
</many-to-one>
```

The above is not working. While fetching a record it tries to fetch LOB code from table2 which is not at all exist in Table1

Comment: Would you please post code for both the classes and the output which you're getting.

Comment: If the second table has no ref to LOB than you can not map the composite key. Can you add a LOB column to table2?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `table2.SK` is a FK to `table1.ID` and there are no `table1` entries having the same ID, you could write the mapping as follows:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Class1 class1Obj;
```

If there are more `table1` rows with the same ID, the mapping will fail because a Child would then be matched to multiple Parents.

So, for a proper `many-to-one` association you need a FK to a Parent column that's unique.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but the above mapping is failing since table1 has composite-id declared in hibernate mapping, many-to-one is also asking for a same number of columns

Comment: I know it works with JPA annotations, but for the old Hibernate specific XML configs, I'm not sure what's the equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate `@Id` does not have to correspond to the real database primary key (although it is desirable that they match, of course).

If `ID` is a unique column in `Table1`, then map Hibernate id only to it, and leave `LOB` as just an ordinary field.

If `ID` is not a unique column, then your many-to-one will not work properly anyway, because there would be multiple matching rows in the referenced table.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Table_name")
public class table_name {
@EmbeddedId
@AttributeOverrides({
@AttributeOverride(name = "id1", column = @Column(name = "col1")),
@AttributeOverride(name = "id2", column = @Column(name = "col2")) })
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation to your answer?

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A
[proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve
its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make
it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer
to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.